# VBA Paste Rows into Different Columns

Tags: vba, excel

How can I change my code so that when it copies into sheet2, the rows start at column C? Currently, they are copied into sheet2 at column A.

```
Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
Dim firstRowWs1 As Long
Dim lastRowWs1 As Long
Dim lastRowWs2 As Long
Dim searchColumnWs1 As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim check As Variant
Dim strSearch As Variant
Set ws1 = Worksheets("sheet1")
Set ws2 = Worksheets("sheet2")

With ws2
lastRowWs1 = ws1.UsedRange.Rows.Count
lastRowWs2 = ws2.UsedRange.Rows.Count
firstRowWs1 = 1
searchColumnWs1 = 10
strSearch = Array("asdf", "fdsa")

For i = firstRowWs1 To lastRowWs1
    For Each check In strSearch
        If check = ws1.Cells(i, searchColumnWs1).Value Then
            ws1.Rows(i).Copy (ws2.Rows(lastRowWs2 + 1))
            lastRowWs2 = lastRowWs2 + 1
            ws1.Rows(i).Delete shift:=xlUp
            i = i - 1
            Exit For
        End If
    Next check
Next i
End With
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't - if you copy an entire row you have to paste it into an entire row (ie starting at A) otherwise it won't fit. What you can do is either copy less than the entire row

```
Application.intersect(ws1.Rows(i), ws1.usedrange).Copy ws2.cells(lastrowws2+1, 3)
```

or at the end of your routine just insert two columns at A to push everything across to the right

```
 ws2.columns("A:B").insert xltoright
```